# macOS as 802.1X supplicant: how to choose different EAP method on a wired network?

Tags: ethernet, 802.1x

I'm studying access control on wired network using 802.1X and I'm managed to setup a **FreeRADIUS** server to work with a managed L2 switch, using self-signed certificate instead of the built-in "snake-oil" cert. I'm using my MacBook Pro (Intel) as supplicant to test the setup. When I plugin the Ethernet, macOS prompts me to confirm the certificate, then asks for username / password, and then the Ethernet port is enabled. So it's considered as a success.

The problem is: I've setup other EAP methods on FreeRADIUS server, including EAP-MD5 (yeah I know it's a bad idea but I'm just experimenting) and EAP-TLS. But all the documents I can find on the Internet suggest me to seek MDM solutions.

So the question is: is there any tool I can use to test other EAP method like EAP-MD5 or EAP-TLS ?

P.S.: I've downloaded the last version of `wpa_supplicant` and tried to build `eapol_test`, but it doesn't compile either on my MacBook or on the Linux machine running Rocky 8.